# Python list of dict to html table (Flask)

Tags: python, flask, html-table

I have a list of dict:

```py
data = [{'2479': {'2022-09-04 to 2022-09-10': 28, '2022-08-28 to 2022-09-03': 27},
 'ADMINISTRATION': {'2022-09-04 to 2022-09-10': 8},
 '1361': {'2022-09-04 to 2022-09-10': 4, '2022-08-28 to 2022-09-03': 5},
 'PERSONAL TIME OFF': {'2022-08-28 to 2022-09-03': 8}}]

# '2479' is the project number
# '2022-09-04 to 2022-09-10' is the date range
# 28 is the total number of hours used for the project for that week
```

I'm trying to convert it to an html table like this:
[image]

So far, this is what I have:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
{% macro render_table_header(label) %}
        {% for record in content["weeklyUserReport"] %}
        {% for project in record %}
        {% for week in record[project] %}
        <th class="rotate-45 week1">
          <div><span class="date">{{week}}</span></div>
        </th>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endmacro %}

      <table
        class="table table-header-rotated table-striped-column hours-container"
        id="grid"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="row-header"></th>
            {{ render_table_header() }}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for record in content["weeklyUserReport"] %}
          {% for project in record %}
          {% for week in record[project] %}
          <tr>
            {% if record[project] == project %}
            <td class="project-name"></td>
            {% else %}
            <td class="project-name">{{ project }}</td>
            {% endif %}
            <td class="week1">{{ record[project][week] }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I'd like duplicated projects to be removed and for the hours to line in to their corresponding rows. I have `<td class="week2">`, `<td class="week3">`, and `<td class="week4">` for the other hours but I'm struggling to find a way to do that.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were confused about how to properly do loops through the list of dictionaries on the jinja template. I can give a "replica" of what you have done. Try to do something like this on your HTML:

```
<body>
    <table class="table table-header-rotated table-striped-column hours-container" id="grid" style="border: 1px solid black">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black">project name</th>
                {% for d in date %}
                    <th class="row-header" style="border: 1px solid black">{{d}}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for record in data %}
                {% for project_key, project_value in record.items() %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ project_key }}</td>
                    {% for value in project_value.values() %}
                        <td class="week1" style="border: 1px solid black">{{ value }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Here is my controller:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    data = [{'2479': {'2022-09-04 to 2022-09-10': 28, '2022-08-28 to 2022-09-03': 27},
                'ADMINISTRATION': {'2022-09-04 to 2022-09-10': 8},
                '1361': {'2022-09-04 to 2022-09-10': 4, '2022-08-28 to 2022-09-03': 5},
                'PERSONAL TIME OFF': {'2022-08-28 to 2022-09-03': 8
            }}]
    date = ['2022-09-04', '2022-08-28']

    return render_template('index.html', date=date, data=data)
```

Here is the result I got:

[image: Table render result]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. I didn't know you could do `{% for project_key, project_value in record.items() %}` that kind of loop so I'm gonna look into that. Have a great day!